# UIViewController auto rotate?

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I setup my UIViewController in app delegate as self.window.rootViewController. For some reason I need open sign view as modal from my root view controller like:

```
            self.window.rootViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
            [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:signViewC animated:NO];
```

If I change device orientation in sign view, my root view controller doesn't change orientation and I get incorrect orientation after sign view dismissed. Is it possible to change root view orientation if I changed orientation in sign view?

In my root controller I added:

```
     - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
     {
        return YES;
     }
```

And autorotation works if I rotate root view without modal view.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't be presenting a modal from your app delegate. Whatever check you are doing to determine if you should present that view controller should be done in your main view controller. From there, you should call the code to present the modal, like so:

```
[self presentModalViewController:signViewC animated:NO]
```

That way, your main view controller isn't dismissed, it's only pushed down the view stack and should still respond to rotation notifications.

Try that out and let me know how it turns out.

**EDIT**

Take out the ModalPresentationStyle. That's what's messing you up.

Comment: Where are you calling those lines?

Comment: What do you mean? It is in implementation .m file. It is generated by default. Or I need to do something else?

Comment: The 2 lines where you call presentModalViewController, which file did you take copy them from?

Comment: I need ModalPresentationStyle for sign view, because I am using transparent background for sign view. Without that background is black. And self.window.rootViewController is my root view controller which always present. I applied something like this:         MyRootViewController * view = [[MyRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyRootViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = view;